# Keeping the structure of SSRS Table common

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset which returns the top 5 rows from a table and I display the data in SSRS Table. Now I need to maintain the 5 rows Table structure even if the number of rows returned by the dataset is 0 or less than 5. How can i acheive this.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities.

---

1) You could add five Footer rows to the table and set the RowVisibility expression to `= CountRows() > 0` through to `= CountRows() > 4`.

[image]

---

2) You could hack about with the query that populates the dataset such that it always returns exactly 5 rows.

e.g. Suppose your current query is

```
SELECT TOP (5) name,
               create_date
FROM   sys.objects
ORDER  BY create_date
```

You could change that to

```
WITH TopFive
     AS (SELECT TOP (5) name,
                        create_date,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY create_date) AS RN
         FROM   sys.objects
         ORDER  BY create_date)
SELECT TF.name,
       TF.create_date
FROM   (VALUES(1),
              (2),
              (3),
              (4),
              (5)) V(N)
       LEFT JOIN TopFive TF
         ON TF.RN = V.N 
ORDER BY TF.RN
```